# Number occurrences into a list

Tags: scheme

This is an example of what the program have to do:

```
(count ‘(1 2 3 4 5 6)) => (1 1 1 1 1 1)

(count ‘(6 8 3 6 6 1)) => (1 0 1 0 0 3 0 1)
```

Every occurrence of a number in input list have to be counted in appropriate index of output list.

Can you please help me find the solution?

Comment: How far have you come on your solution? Where are you stuck? It's not obvious as the question has no questions in it. You should perhaps edit your post with a specific problem and the code you have so far to show effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of easy solution with `build-list` and `foldr`:

```
(define (count l)
  (build-list (apply max l)
              (lambda (i)
                (foldr (lambda (x y) (if (= x (+ i 1)) (+ y 1) y)) 0 l))))
```

---

```
(count '(6 8 3 6 6 1)) ;==> (1 0 1 0 0 3 0 1)
```